# Android Wear (5.0) with Android Marshmallow's permission model

Tags: android, permissions, geolocation, wear-os, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm in the middle of building a Wear App for an existing phone app.

We plan on targeting API 23 and modifying our phone app's location permissions to work with Android new runtime permission model (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

I was trying to figure out how the Wearable device running Android 5.0 is going to work once we do that. From what I've learnt when asking for locations for the Wearable from https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html:

- The wearable may or may not have a GPS radio present. For wearables that do not have a radio, the location data comes from the tethered device.
- We don’t need to worry about the source of location data – FusedLocationProvider (as part of the Google Play Service) handles this for you behind the scene.
- We are responsible for handling the edge case where the wearable does not have GPS hardware (can be checked via hasSystemFeature()) and if the tethering is interrupted (can be detected via WearableListenerService). An example of this would be when the user goes for a run without the phone. In this case, we are expected to degrade the functionality gracefully.

What’s puzzling me is how this will work when we migrate to the new Marshmallow permission model.

Android Wear is not affected if the hardware has on board GPS since no wear devices run Android 6.0 and the old permission model applies. The problem would come about if a wear device with no GPS hardware is tethered to a device running Android 6.0. In this case, if the wear device requests for the location, it would passed on to the phone and the user has not been asked permission/or has disabled the permission, how will this work at all?

I'm imagining that need to hack around this:

- On wearable app start, first check if the hardware has a GPS radio
- If no, send a message to the phone to ask if holds the permission for requesting location (use the data sync APIs for this)
- If the answer comes back false, then show a message to the user on the wearable and ask if they want to resolve it on the phone.
- If the user answers “yes”, push a message to the phone to show an activity where it would just prompt  for permission.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes You logic is perfect. I worked like this in my case. In developer site, it is described like your logic. Enjoy!!!!